# Android App development what is better browser based or pure java based

Tags: android

I have an app that has requirements for various hardware needs on the adroid platform, such as the gps, camera, storage, etc. But this app is also going to communicate constantly while in use with a web based service. Its an extension of that service kinda like how facebook has an app for its services, well I have a similar requirement.

My problem is I am unfamiliar with Android development other than its based on the SDK and JAVA. So I am wondering are apps like the facebook app a browser-esk based application where some of the buttons controlling the app are for connecting  to the hardware, or is the app a purely java based rendition of the web counter part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook for Android app is a *native* app written in Java. If your app is going to interface with Android hardware, then **yes**, you're going to need to write a native app.

You do have the option of writing a web-based app (run from the browser) which will end up being cross-platform but keep in mind that you'll lose native hardware integration and *might* sacrifice usability as well.

Comment: Thank you, it was hard to tell the difference, cause I know when I go to the m.facebook.com URL it looks almost exactly like the the App itself, which drove me to question are they in a sense running a browser in sorts through an app that has the ability to connect to the phones hardware and still remain a service otherwise. But I think you just solidified the answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

For the time i prefer go for native app development because it can be used offline. While if you go for Web based that needs an active data connection.